# Ubuntu 15.04 has very poor PPTP connectivity

Tags: networking, vpn, 15.04, pptp

Under my university circumstances, I should connect to a PPTP VPN to access to the Internet. Thus a high performance and bug-free PPTP client is a essence for me.

When I was using Ubuntu 14.04 and 14.10, the PPTP client was working fine. But as of I replaced my Ubuntu by 15.04, my PPTP connectivity has gone toward a very bad experience.

**What I am currently experiencing:**

When I connect to the PPTP by clicking on the VPN name in the `nm-applet`, it connects in a usual manner and gives me a good connectivity only around 30sec to 60sec but from this time onwards connection speed drops down dramatically such that when I want to load a web page only its title is loaded and rest of that page will not be shown.

When I disconnect and connect again, such behavior will be repeated.

**My questions:**

- Can anyone please suggect me a way to improve my default PPTP client?
- Is it possible for me to use 3rd party PPTP clients? If so, which is the best?

**Context:**

- `pptp` version : 1.7.2
- Underlying interface: Intel Centrino Wireless N 2230

Answer (score 1):

Seems it could be mitigated by updating the `pptp` client to version 1.8.0. Instructions is listed as follows.

- Download the latest client from [PPTP client repository on Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pptpclient/files/pptp/)
- Extract that archive file and read a file called `INSTALL`. (For convenience I have listed its contents here)

> Installation Instructions - Detailed
>
> 1. install PPP, and make sure it is working.
>
>    On most distributions, use the package called ppp or pppd.
>
>    If your PPTP server requires MPPE, make sure the pppd program
>         has been built with MPPE and MS-CHAP support.  PPP from
>         version 2.4.2 onwards has this support.  PPP may require
>         kernel support for MPPE, which may require patching your
>         kernel.
> 2. verify that the pppd program is in the /usr/sbin/ directory.
>
>    ```
>    On some distributions, it is in /usr/bin, or somewhere else.
>    If it isn't in the default directory, edit the Makefile, and
>    change the PPPD variable to point at the pppd program.
>
>    You may even want to run a separate pppd program with MPPE
>    support.
>    ```
> 3. compile
>
>    ```
>    Type 'make'.  This should generate the 'pptp' executable.
>    ```
> 4. install binaries
>
>    Type 'make install' to have the program and the manual page
>      installed.